# Redirect After Submit php [duplicate1]

Tags: php

This is my code:

```
<input type="submit" name="send" class="do__order" value="order" >
```

Now, I want to redirect the submitted to any page of my choice after the form data has been submitted, how do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line to the script:

`header('Location: http://www.example.com/');`

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this on page where you do your check. Let's say it's the `check.php`

```
if(isset($_POST['send'])){
   header('Location: somewhere.php');
}
```

And you also need to add a `method` attribute to your `form` tag, in this case it would be `post`, so `method="post"` and `action` would be `action="check.php"`.